# Flutter command not found and PATH is confusing

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't use the Flutter command without it saying `zsh: command not found: flutter` so I can't create a flutter project which is obviously a necessity.

I have installed Flutter by following the instructions on the site. I set the $PATH how it said to in the docs as well, the first time. I removed flutter from the terminal and reinstalled it but I may have made the situation worse.

Here's what I've done so far:

Put the Flutter SDK in my root folder, I know where it is so that is how I set my $PATH in my `.zshrc` file `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/kentwilson/flutter/bin"`

I have run `echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"` and this is the result:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/Applications/mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.2.0/bin
/usr/local/share/dotnet
~/.dotnet/tools
Users/kentwilson/Development/flutter/bin
~/flutter/bin
```

The second from the bottom is from when I had the Flutter installed before.

This is where I am falling apart. I am illiterate when it comes to my computer environment. Everything else I've ever installed required no effort and I miss that.

Decade old MacBook Pro, Catalina 10.15.7 macOS. I know I'm running zsh, I know where the `.zshrc` is. I have the powerlevel10k installed. Here are my user config lines:

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/kentwilson/flutter/bin"
```

I've tried it with the double quotes and without. I've tried to find other places that might have a PATH somewhere. Nothing. I've googled a few times and when others simply set the PATH and it fixed the issue but not for me.

Aside from these things, I know nothing. Help me. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with zsh, but it seems odd that your `PATH` seems to have `~/flutter/bin` with a *literal* `~` character instead of your actual home directory.  That also doesn't seem to correspond with what's in your `.zshrc` file.  After you updated your .`zshrc` file, did you reload it or restart your shell?

Comment: Additionally, provided `.zshrc` has `/Users/kentwilson/flutter/bin` whereas echoed `PATH` indicates `Users/kentwilson/Development/flutter/bin`. Note the difference in initial `/` character, which could be significant.

Comment: I know! The tilde was weird to me so i used the actual path and restarted the terminal by source and literally quitting it and restarting.

Answer (score 0):

(Optional)
Find where `~/flutter/bin` is added to the PATH and delete the line.
Find where `Users/kentwilson/Development/flutter/bin` is and delete the line. 
You should be able to `grep -nr "flutter/bin" * 2> /dev/null` from home directory. It might take a while.

(Recommended)
Install FVM https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/installation
Add following lines to .zshrc

```bash
# Flutter
FLUTTER_HOME=$HOME/.fvm/flutter_sdk/
export PATH="$FLUTTER_HOME/bin/cache/dart-sdk:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.pub-cache/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/fvm/default/bin:$PATH"
```

There is a GUI as well for fvm named SideKick which handles multiple flutter versions/channels super easy.